# Nginx map confusion

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up some dynamic rate limit for my website to protect it in case of huge traffic. I know on some odd occasions I got spikes (of a couple of hours of crazy out of the normal use when the normal usage can increase even 10 fold. )

Here is how I tried to set it up:

```
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;

map $connections_active $response_rate {
        ~\b([1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]\{2\}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|1000)\b 0;
        ~\b(100[1-9]|10[1-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]\{2\}|2000)\b 62k;
        ~\b(200[1-9]|20[1-9][0-9]|2[1-9][0-9]\{2\}|3000)\b 41k;
        ~\b(300[1-9]|30[1-9][0-9]|3[1-9][0-9]\{2\}|4000)\b 31k;
        ~\b(400[1-9]|40[1-9][0-9]|4[1-9][0-9]\{2\}|5000)\b 25k;
        default 10k;

}

         log_format x 'Current active connection: $connections_active , rate limit set to: $response_rate';


server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {

        limit_rate $response_rate;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log x;

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
.................................................etc
```

I did use loader.io to test if it's working correctly and surely it did seem to, since the log is quite big and there is no point of uploading it all to pastebin I'm including relevant bits:
starts like this:

```
Current active connection: 1 , rate limit set to: 0
Current active connection: 2 , rate limit set to: 0
Current active connection: 916 , rate limit set to: 0
```

All good till here, later in the log:

```
Current active connection: 1029 , rate limit set to: 62k
```

Again this is correct as it's suppose to set the limit to 62k if active users are between 1000 and 2000
But then this happens:

```
Current active connection: 1126 , rate limit set to: 62k
Current active connection: 1246 , rate limit set to: 10k
```

After that stage the rate limit stayed at 10k:

```
Current active connection: 2 , rate limit set to: 10k
```

What am I doing wrong, why is the mapped value not being updated?
Also why did the regex evaluation jumped, from evaluating correctly to the default?

Thank you.

**Update 1**
For the time being till I don't find a better solutions I stopped using map and I added some if statements, but I will much prefer to use map instead:

```
server {
        set $response_rate 5k;
        if ($connections_active ~ "\b([1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|1000)\b")
        {
                set $response_rate 0;
        }

        if ($connections_active ~ "\b(100[1-9]|10[1-9][0-9]|1[1-9][0-9]{2}|2000)\b")
        {
                set $response_rate 62k;
        }

        if ($connections_active ~ "\b(200[1-9]|20[1-9][0-9]|2[1-9][0-9]{2}|3000)\b")
        {
                set $response_rate 41k;
        }

        if ($connections_active ~ "\b(300[1-9]|30[1-9][0-9]|3[1-9][0-9]{2}|4000)\b")
        {
                set $response_rate 32k;
        }

        if ($connections_active ~ "\b(400[1-9]|40[1-9][0-9]|4[1-9][0-9]{2}|5000)\b")
        {
                set $response_rate 25k;
        }

        if ($connections_active ~ "\b(500[1-9]|50[1-9][0-9]|5[1-9][0-9]{2}|6[0-9]{3}|7[0-4][0-9]{2}|7500)\b")
        {
                set $response_rate 10k;
        }

#       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log x;

        limit_rate $response_rate;


        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
...................etc
```

Comment: Have you tried writing the `map` regular expressions the same as your `if` block? Without the backslash braces and instead placing the expression within quotes?

Comment: @RichardSmith - The Regex won't work at all. Yes I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slightly different REGEX? 0-999, 1000-1999, etc.

```
~\b([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9])\b 0;
~\b(1[0-8][0-9]{2}|19[0-8][0-9]|199[0-9])\b 62k;
~\b(2[0-8][0-9]{2}|29[0-8][0-9]|299[0-9])\b 41k;
~\b(3[0-8][0-9]{2}|39[0-8][0-9]|399[0-9])\b 31k;
~\b(4[0-8][0-9]{2}|29[0-8][0-9]|499[0-9])\b 25k;
default 10k;
```

Comment: Thanks, but similar kind of experience. Now it did not jumped to the default value, but when the clients decreased the rate limit did not increase. I start having a feeling it's something to do with the size of the hash_map used for the map function.